# Basic R malfunction

Tags: r

R beginner. Why doesn't this code return the number 3?

```
my_mean <- function(my_vector){
  sum(my_vector)/length(my_vector)
  my_mean
}
my_vector <- c(1, 3, 5)
my_mean
```

I'm not allowed to use `mean()`. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Returning a value by assigning to the function name is Visual Basic syntax. To my knowledge, no other language uses this technique.

If you want to return a value in R, use the `return()` statement:

```
mymean <- function(x)
{
    val <- sum(x)/length(x)
    return(val)
}
```

But there's a shorter way to achieve the same result. If R reaches the end of a function without an explicit `return`, it will return the value of the last expression it found.

```
mymean <- function(x)
{
    val <- sum(x)/length(x)
    val                      # value of last expression is returned
}
```

But this can be shortened further. The variable `val` is only used once, as the last statement in the function. So we could omit it entirely, and just return the computed value itself without storing it in a variable first:

```
mymean <- function(x)
{
    sum(x)/length(x)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I made a mistake in the way I called the function. The call should be:

```
my_mean(c(1,3,5))
```

not:

```
my_vector <- c(1, 3, 5)
my_mean
```